# jQuery remove script effect came from ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, modal-dialog

I have customised nested modal script ([jQueryModal](https://jquerymodal.com/)) to better match project need, but I'm facing some weird issue that I am unable to get

I call that modal to load some contents via ajax, and response from that ajax contains some javascript code along with html and appneds to modal body.
All those javascript code (from ajax response) works perfectly.

Then, when that modal is closed I remove whole modal block and it's content (that ajax responded html + javascript)

But when I reopen same modal, old script has left effect

Example, **Modal A** opened with ajax content, in that content there's **[BUTTON]** to call another ajax (will open another modal), lets call it **Modal B**

In **Modal B**, there's select dropdown which calls ajax on change, which is fine so far.
Now I close **Modal B** and reopen it by clicking that same **[BUTTON]** on **Modal A**, and then **Modal B** opens but this time **Modal B's** select dropdown will call twice upon change

I doubt remove js code on modal close is not enough

What could be problem and solution for that?
Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Removing `<script>` tags does not affect what scripts are loaded by the browser.  All the `<script>` is used for is parsing the script and loading it into the browser memory.

Comment: @Taplar what could be possible solution for this? if i want to keep scripts loading in ajax response

Comment: In Modal B, there's select dropdown which calls ajax on change, which is fine so far. Now I close Modal B and reopen it by clicking that same [BUTTON] on Modal A, and then Modal B opens **but this time Modal B's select dropdown will call twice upon change**, <= that is an indicator of duplicate event bindings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Taplar for help, I got the problem and could able to solve it by little googleing and solution was to use jQuery's [off](https://api.jquery.com/off/)

example:

`$('.button').off('click').on('click', function(){ ... });`

same way for select dropdown:

```
$('select').off('change').on('change', function() { ... });
```